# postfix: send DSN to the "Reply-To" address

Tags: postfix, dsn

is there a way to configure the postfix so that he will sends the DSN (Delivery Status Notifications) messages to the "Reply-To" adrees and not to the "from" address.

Background: The "from" address is a invalid email address (doNotReply@....) but the "Reply-To" address is filled with a correct email address.

Anybody knows if that is possible?

Thanks and regards,
Steffen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DSN actually goes to the Envelope From address, not the From Address inside of the email. Usually anyway.